# Kafka - C# - confluent-kafka-dotnet - Message time out

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, timeout, confluent-platform

We have a simple standalone mode deployment of Kafka 1.1.0 on our Linux machine. In a server.properties we have modified:

```
listeners = PLAINTEXT://10.0.5.66:9092
```

`advertised.listeners` is commented out so it shall fall back to the default value found in `listeners` property.

We are using a .NET (C#) producer which is pushing messages through confluent-kafka-dotnet (0.11.4).
Sometimes the message gets transferred to Kafka and sometimes we receive "Message time out" error on the producer side.
We are running out of ideas of what might cause this issue. It happens from time to time. If one message fails, another which comes few seconds after the first one usually passes.

Another trace could be that from time to time we see the following message in the Kafka logs on the server: `WARN: Attempting to send a response via a channel for which there is no open connection <IP:PORT>`. This message sometimes contains the IP Address and port of the producer.

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution for this problem?,

Comment: Hi @sajadre, we indeed have found the root cause. Our Kafka was hosted in a Virtual machine on a server, which was not dedicated - i.e. it was sharing underlying disk IOPS with other virtual machines. This server was getting backed up few times a day which was efficiently consuming all available IOPS and that's why Kafka started timeouting messages. We diagnosed by seeing a strong correlation between IOPS being used and frequency of messages. Recommendation is to always use dedicated setup if not done so.